# How to see assertions, that have passed successfully in result tree

Tags: report, jmeter, assertions, listeners

A the moment when I execute some tests, I can see only the failed assertions in the result tree listener.
Since I would like to do functional testing with this tools, I need to have all passed validations included in the report.
Is it possible in the new version of `Jmeter`?

Answer (score 1):

You can "tell" JMeter to store results as XML - it will trigger saving assertion results in .jtl file

To switch JMeter results file to XML and store all assertion results add the next two lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
```

You'll get output like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample t="340" lt="340" ts="1430219540110" s="true" lb="HTTP Request" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="1591" ng="1" na="1">
  <assertionResult>
<name>Response Assertion</name>
<failure>false</failure>
<error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
</httpSample>
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of controlling them.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!
Actually i would like to see my successful assertions into the result tree as well ( marked with green) as the request itself.

Comment: Looking into the code of [ViewResultsFullVisualizer](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/components/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java) class which is responsible for View Results Tree listener, it displays in GUI only failed assertions so I'm afraid the only way to achieve your goal is removing `if (item.isFailure() || item.isError()) {` clause and recompiling JMeter.